# Почему не отображаются метки на карте google для mac, iphone?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps-api, google-maps

Доброе утро всем! 
есть вот такой сайт https://podkovacard.ru , на котором есть блок с картой ("Наши партнеры"), на которой куча меток, метки кастомные и задаются в админке (Wordpress), почему то на mac-ах и iphone не отображаются они, вообще пусто , на других устройствах все работает 
какие мысли есть по этому поводу? поделитесь пожалуйста, заказчик не отстает)

Comment: В консоли проверяли на маке? Ошибки есть?

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/5264#5264)

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо получить доступ к MyMaps в мобильном браузере, как и на рабочем столе. Кроме того, в магазине приложений есть несколько сторонних приложений, которые утверждают, что имеют возможность доступа и отображения пользовательских карт Maps Engine Lite. Одним из таких приложений является приложение MapsEngine Viewer
[*Тык*](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fus%2Fapp%2Fmapsengine-viewer%2Fid783537830%3Fmt%3D8&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGZ0mItwaGpJVXnrup_PRO3WJNvKw)